# Check a column of data for data to be other than integer, and delete the contents of cells that are not integers

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a macro in Excel that will delete cells in a specific column if they are not integers, then check the data left for value's greater than .8 and turn the cell red and text white. I can do the 2nd part no problem, but i have mixed data types (text and numbers) and empty cells scattered through out -  and cannot figure out how to only remove the contents on the cells with something other than a number in it.

I only want to clear the contents of the cells that have non-number data so i can run the conditional formatting code i already have.

sample data:

| Column F |
| --- |
| 2023 |
|  |
| 73% |
| 50% |
| 9% |
| 16% |
| 4pm |
| Sep |
|  |
| ? |

i need the cells with "4pm", "Sep" & "?" (this data will change) to be emptied.  The column's length can vary but would never be more than 200 rows.

this is my current code, but i need it to only work on cells with integers, i need the rest to be either emptied - or better yet - no formatting at all

```
' Verify diskstats (looking for >80%)
'

'


Dim r As Range, arr, i
    Set r = Range([F1], Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    arr = r.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        ' Validate and clean non-numeric cell
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then arr(i, 1) = ""
    Next
    r.Value = arr

    
 'between 1 & 80% turns green
    
     Columns("F:F").Select
    
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0.00000001", Formula2:="=0.8"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    'greater than 80% turns red
    
    Columns("F:F").Select
    If Right(Selection.NumberFormat, 1) = "%" Then
    
    
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=0.8"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If
    
   ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide code will clean the non-numeric cells in Column F.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim r As Range, arr, i
    Set r = Range([F1], Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    arr = r.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        ' Validate and clean non-numeric cell
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then arr(i, 1) = ""
    Next
    r.Value = arr
End Sub
```

---

Updated code to answer the question in comment.

```
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range([F1], Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(r.Value) Then r.Value = ""
        If Right(r.NumberFormat, 1) = "%" Then
            r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
                Formula1:="=0.8"
            r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With r.FormatConditions(1).Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With r.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With r.FormatConditions(1).Font
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you.  One other thing that would make my report viewer absolulty perfect would be if it only changed the cells showing a % sign red when looking for anything over 80%.  I can make it do between 80 & 1 but it still highlights the cells that don't have the percent sign.

The data is copied from an emailed report so its kind of like a csv data sheet when I paste it into excel so the number only cells are auto formatted to general, and the ones with the percent sign are autoformatted to percent.  when i look at the cell in the address bar, it shows the % sign

Comment: i have tried adding an if statement: 

> If Right(Selection.NumberFormat, 1) = "%" Then />
and the respective end if...
but then none of the cells are conditionally formatted...  so how do i make it look for the cells that are hard coded as a percent?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question w/o seeing more code.

Comment: same code as before, I added your code to mine at the top -  then added the if right line in the >80 section:

Comment: i modified original code post to current code...

Comment: You need loop through cells in Column F. I have updated the code to combine cleaning cells and part of setting conditional format.